# Guaranteeing CurrentUICulture across InvokeAsync invocations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor-server-side

Since the renderer dispatcher is not a *thread* dispatcher, and multiple `InvokeAsync` invocations might use different threads, is there any way I can guarantee `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` will be the same on all invocations?

My application's Culture is dynamic (it's stored on session and does not come from the asp's localization middleware, plus it can be changed dynamically within the SignalR circuit and does not need to open a new http connection) and the current culture is stored on each component, however events called from a different circuit (which might have a different culture) might want to change something in a component instance rendered in other users.

I store the component's `CultureInfo` in the component itself, but I'm trying to avoid having to do all the `ToString(Culture)` or `@bind-X:culture="@Culture"` on the templates, since it's both verbose and a bit cumbersome (and prone to forgetness and mistakes), so whenever the component's culture changes, I do something like:

```
await InvokeAsync(() => CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = newCulture));
```

Is this enough so that other calls to that component's `InvokeAsync` (and the renderer dispatcher) will correctly get the thread's culture?

It *does seem to work*, but I haven't seen this guaranteed in any documentation (nor `InvokeAsync` guaranteeing local thread values will be kept between different invocations)

### Update

I made a simple test page (I've added the source code here: https://gist.github.com/javiercampos/1152da404c3004d7fbaac8e503425e4a ), and the `CurrentCulture`/`CurrentUICulture` definitely doesn't:

- Flow with async on the component's context
- Change at all if you change it on a `InvokeAsync()`

So tough luck here, unless someone adds that flow to the actual [renderer synchronization context](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Components/src/Rendering/RendererSynchronizationContext.cs)

I've made a request for the feature: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35965

Comment: How do you think to handle a re-connect?

Comment: Does Culture-per-Component mean you could have different cultures on 1 page?

Comment: @HenkHolterman theoretically yes, but in practice, it's one per layout/circuit (it's a cascading value above the main RouteView that components in the page get through a cascading parameter), so I'd be ok just making sure the renderer takes the one in the "routable component/page".

Comment: If I was to have different cultures on different components on the same page then I understand I'd need to specify it in the rendering of the template always, but that's not the practical case

Comment: It seems in legacy asp.net (not core, where there isn't one), the [synchronization context](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/AspNetSynchronizationContext.cs) was actually associated with the thread, thus flowing also the `CultureInfo` associated with the thread. It doesn't look like so in the [Blazor one](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8b30d862de6c9146f466061d51aa3f1414ee2337/src/Components/Components/src/Rendering/RendererSynchronizationContext.cs). I'll need to make some tests here